# coverting numbers in words. Using if else statments

Tags: python-3.x

i need to convert numbers in words using python with arrays. Example 0 - 999 what will be the output of this. Using if else statments

Comment: The info you provided is not enough. You must provide more info otherwise this question will be closed.

Answer (score 1):

You can create variables to do this and then arrays.

For example :

```
var num = <the number displayed / the value of a text input where numbers are written>

alphabets = [start,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z]

x = alphabets[num]

print(x)
```

The reason I wrote "start" in the beginning of the array is because arrays start at 0, not 1. Instead of doing num-1 I just did this. You can do `x = alphabets[num-1]` and remove "start" from the array altogether but whatever works for you. Just saying, this code might not work but this is just for reference so you get what you can do. If you want to use if statements (which makes your code extremely long but whatever), then you can try this :

```
if(num === 1){
print(a)
}
if(num === 2){
print(b)
}
if(num === 3){
print(c)
}
```

And so on till z or whatever you want. With this, you can change what the print value should be per number and even do random numbers like

```
if(num === 69){
print(nice)
}
```

without having 68 elements in your array.

Again, whatever works for you. If you want more info, you can visit this w3schools website for other commands like pop(), remove(), etc.

Link : https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_arrays.asp

Comment: You haven't answered in Python syntax. this may be confusing to the person who asked the question.

Comment: Welp, sorry. I mainly do javascript and such so my syntax may be a little off. But it's just the thought process. If you understand what it means it should work in python as well. Most coding languages are similar regardless of the terminology. Plus the website I linked is for python so that reference should be fine. If you need any clarification I would be glad to help.